# Increase a png img size, without loosing resolution,

Tags: html, css, png

I have searched everywhere if this is possible, and it seems like it doesn´t. My last chance s with you my fellow coders. I have a 200px png img. I want to use it but bigger, at least 300px, without loosin resolution. Is tha possibe with html or css?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: No you can't increase the size of an image without losing resolution, using HTML or CSS. The best you can do is to resize it in something like Photoshop using Bicubic Smoother interpolation. Even then, it's not going to be perfect.

Comment: Ok @MichaelvE, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I am terribly sorry, but it is not possible to create data from nothing. Those additional pixels literally do not exist. The best you can do is a very capable up-scaling tool that is good at estimating the missing data. Photoshop has some tools for it as well as other image editing software, and those will still not be perfect, but it cannot be done with HTML or CSS. They will only stretch the image and there will be pixelization.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this, it may be the up-scaler you are looking for. As to what additional information the program is going to add to the image in order to make it appear to have fewer defects when enlarged, that depends on how it was trained.

from:
https://github.com/nagadomi/waifu2x

```
    th waifu2x.lua -m scale -i input_image.png -o output_image.png
```